# Tensor data is null

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor, quantization

I have a `.tflite`, then I want to print `Layer 22`, but it can't work, it displays the error, I don't know how to fix.

My code

```
import tensorflow as tf
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path='/content/drive/MyDrive/non_RR/tflite_qaware_model.tflite')
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
print(interpreter.get_tensor(22))
```

The output

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-d40b7ea1229d> in <cell line: 6>()
      4 interpreter.allocate_tensors()
      5 
----> 6 print(interpreter.get_tensor(22))

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter.py in get_tensor(self, tensor_index, subgraph_index)
    874       a numpy array.
    875     """
--> 876     return self._interpreter.GetTensor(tensor_index, subgraph_index)
    877 
    878   def tensor(self, tensor_index):

ValueError: Tensor data is null. Run allocate_tensors() first
```